# Restriction and intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Say $X$ is a smooth threefold, and $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three smooth divisors on $X$.  Is it true that the three-way intersection $(A \cdot B \cdot C)_X$ is equal to the intersection $(A\vert_C \cdot B\vert_C)_C$ computed on $C$?

Geometrically this seems like it should be true, but I'm having a hard time finding a reference.  No doubt it implicit somewhere in Fulton.  In what generality does this work? (e.g. I guess it is still true if $A$ and $B$ are not effective, but maybe not if $C$ is too singular)

Comment: Yes, this is true. This is one of the properties of the intersection pairing; it might be in Lazarsfeld's Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I, or possibly in Badescu's book Algebraic Surfaces. Unfortunately I don't have the books right by me to check.